# Handle mouse event from another process

Tags: c#, process, event-handling

In my program I use class Process to start another application. This application starts fullscreen. My purpose is to handle mouse  click from that application in my program. What WinApi functions should I use?

Comment: you should accept some answers to previous questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "WinApi", I assume that you mean "Win32".

In order to handle messages of another process, you need to install a Win32 hook. See [this article](http://hyper.sunjapan.com.cn/~hz/win32/hooks32.htm) for more details. You need the WH_MOUSE hook and the SetWindowsHookEx Win32 API.

A hook function needs to be in a DLL, so that it can be injected in any process. You will need to filter the messages you get for the process that you started.

A hook function needs to be a global function so you must code it in C++. You will also need to use some inter-process communication to well, communicate with your main program, if needed.